# python strip a comma at the beginning

Tags: python

**I had a question about the the strip method in python.**

```
print(item, end=' ')
```

**My question was this result returns from a list but there is a comma that begins from the second line. How do just remove the second line comma.**

**Output**

```
800,989, hi, hello

,900,108, bye, bye
```

Comment: [`lstrip`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lstrip.html)

Comment: Are these two lines one whole string? Two string elements in a list?

Comment: yes this is from a csv file it brings back two lines from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the following as one string `item`:

```
800,989, hi, hello

,900,108, bye, bye
```

You can split the string in a list of lines first, `lstrip` each line, and then rejoin the list into a string:

```
'\n'.join(i.lstrip(',') for i in item.splitlines())
```

Comment: for some reason it occurs on the second line im not sure why. i tried using the lstrip but its not working

Comment: I've updated my answer so it strips commas from every line in a string. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually specifiy what you would like to strip from the left side by inserting the character in quotes

```
x.lstrip(',')
```